# Background image and text will be fixed on web site

Tags: themes, fixed

https://avada.theme-fusion.com/gym/ [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SzHPf.png) On this   website the text "No Pain No Gain" on the first page is fixed with the background image. But after scrolling it is being hidden? How it is done?

Answer (score 0):

it can be done using postion: fixed , and z-index .